# Standardizing Blazor Startups, use Application Builders in Libraries

Tags: asp.net, blazor, maui-blazor

At work we develop a software system with Blazor and we are thinking about creating desktop applications using our common components and pages too. Currently all of the startups of our webservers is pretty much just copy and pasted and of course that is not exactly ideal. At home I was tooling around with standardizing that and I was successful.

Let me add an example so my goal is more understandable:

My goal is to achieve a 'ApplicationBuilder' that creates and configures an application. I need to be able to use inheritance to de-standardize common builders. Especially since we customize our software for our customers.

This results in something like this:

```
// Common implementation
class CommonAppBuilder
{
    public virtual Application CreateApplication()
    {
        var builder = MauiAppBuilder.CreateBuilder(); // Or some other builder for Blazor Server for example...

        // Configuration of something like a MauiAppBuilder or IConfiguration or our IServiceCollection is done in other methods of this builder that will be invoked at some point in here
    }

    // More stuff ...
}


// Application A implementation (application specific, still a standard application)
class ApplicationAAppBuilder : CommonAppBuilder
{
    public override Application CreateApplication()
    {
        var builder = base.CreateApplication();

        // Here I want to be able to add or intercept (simply override and differ from) the common, standard implementation of configuring and settings up our startup
    }

    // Maybe more overrides if need be...
}

// Customized application A implementation (application and customer specific)
class CustomApplicationAAppBuilder : ApplicationAAppBuilder
{
    public override Application CreateApplication()
    {
        var builder = base.CreateApplication();

        // Same story, I want to be able to inherit and override the respective standard, so I can replace standard parts with parts that need to be customized or simply add more...
    }
}

// Main(string[])
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Everything about the applications configuration takes place in my application builder, so it can be standartized and override if need be
        new CustomApplicationAAppBuilder(args)
            .CreateApplication()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

Now I know this is unconventional, but likely better than copy and pasting something like 25+ standard applications and many more to come custom versions of those applications startups.

I actually managed to get those builders to work, however I currently have the following:

- MAUI Blazor project stripped off of everything except for that kind of builder so I can have access to the MauiAppBuilder
- Blazor Server project stripped off of everything except for that kind of builder so I can have access to the WebAppBuilder. This also has a class with a static main-method in it, since it wont compile otherwise.
- Regular C# project with common extension methods only, so both webservers and desktop applications can share the same extension methods. As far as I have tried, I cant have a Blazor Server reference a MAUI application and the other way around, but even if, I would still have two projects with barely anything in it.
- And of course I still have the Blazor Server webserver and MAUI Blazor Desktop versions of the same program, so two more projects.

I am wondering now:

- Is it possible to add some kind of NuGet package to add MauiAppBuilders and WebAppBuilders to a regular Razor Library to merge these three projects into one? I did not find one, nor managed to 'convert/change' the projects while maintaining the possibilities of using MauiAppBuilders and WebAppBuilders.
- Could this kind of application builder cause any issues? As far as I would expect it shouldnt, but I am sure as hell not all-knowing.
- Is there a better way to achieve what we need?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly.  Then yes there is a cleaner way.  It's the way the DotnetCore Team do it.

For example:

```cs
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddServerComponents();
```

This defines `Extension` methods [for either `WebApplicationBuilder` or `IServiceCollection`] in libraries to define the services required by that library.  You can have multipe methods for different deployments i.e. Blazor Server, WASM, API Server,...

Here's my Infrastructure domain services defined in the Infrastructure project.

```cs
public static class ApplicationInfrastructureServices
{
    public static void AddAppServerInfrastructureServices(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var services = builder.Services;
        var configuration = builder.Configuration;

        var dbConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("DevelopmentConfiguration:DBConnectionString");

        services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString));

        services.AddScoped<IDataBroker, ServerDataBroker>();

        //  lots more Infratructure level services         
  
        // Add any individual entity services
        // Each entity has it's own definitions 
        services.AddGroupServerInfrastructureServices();
    }
}
```

And my Presentation Layer services:

```cs
public static class AppPresentationServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static void AddAppPresentationServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddQuickGridEntityFrameworkAdapter();

        services.AddGroupPresentationServices();
        services.AddUserPresentationServices();
    }
}
```

And finally my Server Web Project program:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddServerComponents();

builder.AddAppServerInfrastructureServices();
builder.AddAppAuthServices();

builder.Services.AddAppPresentationServices();

builder.Services.AddAppUIServices();

var app = builder.Build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fear your suggestion does not achieve what we need. I updated my question so my question gets much clearer.